# Xilinx syntax ERROR:HDLCompiler:806

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am writing a dice or craps game using xilinx for a spartan-6 nexys 3 board.

I am getting these errors saying syntax error near 'if' or 'begin'.
I know I have the correct libraries and I am confident I don't have any silly syntax error (though one can never be absolutely certain of this).

I am hoping an experienced VHDL composer can point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong. 
Thank you in advance!

```
        library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.numeric_bit.ALL;

    -- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
    -- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

    -- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
    -- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
    library UNISIM;
    use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

    entity DiceGame is
         Port ( Rb : in  STD_LOGIC;
                  Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
                  CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
                  Sum : in  integer range 2 to 12;
                  Roll : out  STD_LOGIC;
                  Win : out  STD_LOGIC;
                  Lose : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end DiceGame;

    architecture DiceBehave of DiceGame is
    signal State: integer range 0 to 5;
    signal Nextstate: integer range 0 to 5;
    signal Point: integer range 2 to 12;
    signal Sp: STD_LOGIC;

    begin
        proces(Rb, Reset, Sum, State)
        begin
            Sp <= '0'; Roll<='0'; Win <='0'; Lose<='0';

            case State is

                when 0 => 
                    if Rb='1' then Nextstate <= 1; 
                    end if;

                when 1 =>
                    if Rb='1' then Roll='1';
                    elsif Sum=7 or sum=11 then Nextstate <= 2;
                    else if Sum=2 or Sum=3 or Sum=12 then Nextstate <= 3;
                    else Sp='1'; Nextstate <= 4;
                    end if;

                when 2 =>
                    win <='1';
                    if Reset='1' then Nextstate <= 0;
                    end if;

                when 3 =>
                    Lose <= '1';
                    if Reset='1' then Nextstate <=0;
                    end if;

                when 4 =>
                    if Rb='1' then Nextstate <= 5;
                    --else NextState <=4;
                    end if;

                when 5 =>
                    if Rb='1' then Roll='1';
                    elsif Sum = Point then Nextstate <=2;
                    elsif Sum= 7 then Nextstate <=3;
                    else Nextstate <=4;
                    end if;

            end case;

        end process;

        Process(CLK)
        begin

            if CLK'event and CLK='1' then State<=Nextstate;
                if Sp='1'then Point<= Sum;
                end if;
            end if;

        end process;

    end DiceBehave;
```

Here are my errors:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 51: Syntax error near "begin".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 54: Syntax error near "case".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 58: Syntax error near "if".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 63: Syntax error near "else".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 64: Syntax error near "else".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 65: Syntax error near "if".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 69: Syntax error near "if".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 70: Syntax error near "if".  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital   
WARNING:HDLCompiler:1369 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital   Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 91: Possible infinite loop; process does not have a wait statement  
ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "\\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd" Line 43: Unit <dicebehave> ignored due to previous errors.  
VHDL file \\cdc-data\susers\lreves\Advanced Digital Projects\DICEGAME\DiceGame\DiceBehave.vhd ignored due to errors  
-->   

Total memory usage is 221592 kilobytes  

Number of errors   :   15 (   0 filtered)  
Number of warnings :    1 (   0 filtered)  
Number of infos    :    0 (   0 filtered)  


Process "Synthesize - XST" failed
```

Comment: Line numbers don't correspond with error messages. Please provide the errors from compiling what you posted. However, `Process` is spelled `Proces` which can't help, accounting for the first error. That may be causing the others.

Comment: Your code produces a latch for the signal `NextState`. You can solve this by adding another default assignment to you process. You should also initialize your signal state. Why are you using type integer for State? Enum is such a good construct for state-names ;)

Comment: Good catch, I should have taken a break instead of asking for help. I looked at it for about 45 min looking for syntax errors with no such look. Needed a fresh pair of eyes. It is working properly now. Last step is to get a debouncer working and configure a 7 segment display to show the two die numbers. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 51 misspelled `process` on Line 50  (will collapse the next errors on Lines 54, 58)

Line 63 `Roll='1'` should be `Roll <= '1'`  (Will collapse errors lines 64, 65).

Line 69: `else Sp ='1'; Nextstate <= 4;` should be `else Sp <= '1'; Nextstate <= 4;`

Line 68: (not listed as an error)  `else if` should be `elsif`

Line 88: (not listed as an error) `then Roll = '1';` should be `then Roll <= '1';`

Then this analyzes and elaborates (and we make no claim it is correct, the urge to reformat indentation and whitespace is almost overwhelming).

(And these tells us you should use consistent indentation and whitepace to make these stand out).

Also note the only use clause that is necessary is

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
```

The rest of those use clauses are noise.

(And here's hoping counting on my fingers and toes got the original line numbers right from your error messages and VHDL sample mismatching).

Comment: Be careful of copy-pasting; should be `Nextstate <= 4;`, and I'm not allowed to suggest an edit less than 6 characters.

Comment: Great job, thank you for such a healthy response too. Turns out stressing over finals and such made my syntax detecting skills sag very low. It was all syntax errors. I like the white space but im used to short code lengths. I agree my indenting is poor. Thank you again for your help and information regarding the excess clauses as you say.     Also I worked at an electrical construction company named Koontz, any chance of relation their? based out of arkansas. anyways thanks again David Koontz.